# Jquery move table row up or down or move X

Tags: jquery

I saw the [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1569889/jquery-move-table-row)

but no idea how due to fresh to jquery, is that any way to remove "up" key when it reach to the top and remove "down" key when it is the bottom.

And also, I need have a input to move my certain row to another row, eg: row 1,2,3 and move row 1 to 3 just input 3 and press submit and it move.

Is that any example or tutorial to teach how to do so? as newbie to Jquery, hope someone help me, thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

could you use css formating with [:first-child :last-child](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/firstchild.html) selectors and display:none for the up key:

```
tr:first-child a.up,
tr:last-child a.down {
  diplay: none;
}
```