# Gridview: prevent rows from moving above header row

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, gridview

I'm using jQuery to allow users to move rows one by one and drag and drop. I figured out how to prevent the drag and drop from moving above the header row but can't find a solution for my other option.

The code I used came from this post:
[How to move table row in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1569889/jquery-move-table-row)

I also created a demo here with a header row: http://jsfiddle.net/vaDkF/

Is it possible to find out if the row clicked has a row above it? For example the header index would be zero so the row clicked beneath it would not be allowed to move up.

Any ideas or suggestions, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting your header row in a `<thead>` tag and the rest of your rows in a `<tbody>` will achieve this. You can do this easily on the gridview, I think you have to do this after databinding.

```
GridView1.HeaderRow.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableHeader;
```