# How can jQuery select Table Row group by Colum's value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, gridview, jquery-selectors, onclick

I have a problem regarding jQuery selector, where I have a Table structure as below (**HTML Portion**), and there is a link in table column for click and move the Table Row "UP" and "Down" by using jQuery (**jQuery Portion**, reference from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1569889/jquery-move-table-row/1569919#comment22056889_1569919)).

**jQuery Portion :**

```
 $(".up,.down").click(function() {
    var row = $(this).parents("tr:first");
    if ($(this).is(".up")) {
        row.insertBefore(row.prev("tr:has(td)"));
    } else {
        row.insertAfter(row.next());
    }
});
```

**HTML Portion :**

```
 <table cellspacing="0" border="0" id="Table1" style="text-align:center" >
    <tr>
        <th scope="col" width="80px">Column A</th><th scope="col" width="80px">Column B</th><th scope="col">&nbsp;</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
                <span id="GridView1_ctl02_lbl1">A</span>
            </td><td>
                <span id="GridView1_ctl02_lbl2">0</span>
            </td><td>
                <a href="#" class="up">Up</a> <a href="#" class="down">Down</a>
            </td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td>
                <span id="GridView1_ctl03_lbl1">B</span>
            </td><td>
                <span id="GridView1_ctl03_lbl2">2</span>
            </td><td>
                <a href="#" class="up">Up</a> <a href="#" class="down">Down</a>
            </td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td>
                <span id="GridView1_ctl04_lbl1">C</span>
            </td><td>
                <span id="GridView1_ctl04_lbl2">2</span>
            </td><td>
            </td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td>
                <span id="GridView1_ctl05_lbl1">D</span>
            </td><td>
                <span id="GridView1_ctl05_lbl2">2</span>
            </td><td>
            </td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td>
                <span id="GridView1_ctl06_lbl1">E</span>
            </td><td>
                <span id="GridView1_ctl06_lbl2">3</span>
            </td><td>
                <a href="#" class="up">Up</a> <a href="#" class="down">Down</a>
            </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I wanted the Row to be move "UP" and "Down" **group by values in "Column B"** (as per highlighted with red box") instead of ordinary row by row. Based on example of the diagram, the moving of rows should be move by the red boxes.

[image]

So my question is, how can I using jQuery selector to select rows group by value in "Column B"? which the onclick event was trigger on links ("Up" & "Down") click.

Thank you in advanced :)

Comment: You want so that when you click `up/down` it will move that item, and any items with a corresponding value, such as all items with `2` up if you click up, and down if you click down?

Comment: Hi Ohgodwhy, yes, the row up and down is with the group of 0, 2, and 3

Comment: I believe this is feasible right? something like conditional checking of the Column B values

Comment: yes, sorry, give me a few moments I'll put something together.

Comment: I don't think you can do this with just a selector, but you should be able to do it with `.filter()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you can do this with **Just** selectors and a single command! but you can use some loops :

```
 $(".up,.down").click(function () {
     var row = $(this).parents("tr:first");
     if ($(this).is(".up")) {

         myRow = row;
         prevRow = row.prev("tr");

         currentValue = myRow.children("td").eq(1).text();
         prevValue = prevRow.children("td").eq(1).text();
         parNode = myRow.parent();

         i = 0;
         family = [];
         parNode.children("tr").each(function(){
             if($(this).children("td").eq(1).text() == currentValue){
                 family[i] =  $(this);
                 i++;
             }
         });

         for(var j = 0; j <= i; j++ ){
             while(prevRow.children("td").eq(1).text() == prevValue){
                prevRow = prevRow.prev("tr");
             }
             family[j].insertAfter(prevRow);
         }

     } else {
         row.insertAfter(row.next());
     }
 });
```

Demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/shahverdy/PSDEs/2/
In this demo I implemented only `Up`. Click `Up` for values *2* and *3* to see how it works.

Answer (score 1):

Given the table structure above, you can make a map storing *(value in column b, corresponding `tr` array)* pairs, **if all the rows that have the same value in column B are adjacent**. And when you click the *Up/Down* link, detach all the rows with the same value and get the rows above (for *Up*) or bellow (for *Down*). Then you know where to attach those detached rows.

```
$(function() {
    var column_index = 1;
    function get_value(tr) {
        return $('td', tr).eq(column_index).text().trim();
    }
    function group_by(trs, column_index) {
        var map = {};
        trs.each(function (idx) {
            var value = get_value($(this));
            if (map[value])
                map[value].push($(this));
            else
                map[value] = [$(this)];
        });
        return map;
    }
    var map = group_by($('#Table1 tr:gt(0)'), column_index);

    $('a.up').click(function () {
        var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
        var value = get_value(tr);
        var group = map[value];
        var prev = group[0].prev('tr');
        if (prev.length == 0 || $('th', prev).length != 0)
            return;
        var prev_value = get_value(prev);
        var prev_group = map[prev_value];
        for (var i = 0; i < group.length; i++) {
            group[i].detach();
            prev_group[0].before(group[i]);
        }
    });

    $('a.down').click(function () {
        var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
        var value = get_value(tr);
        var group = map[value];
        var next = group[group.length - 1].next('tr');
        if (next.length == 0)
            return;
        var next_value = get_value(next);
        var next_group = map[next_value];
        for (var i = group.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            group[i].detach();
            next_group[next_group.length - 1].after(group[i]);
        }
    });
});
```

Refer to the code example at [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/52fP5/).

If you generate the table dynamically at the server end, it would be better to do the group with SQL or server end languages, and attach some class to the `tr` to identify the groups.