# Switch Positions of Tablerows only work once

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have made a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eVz69/)

I have a table with articlepositions. And I would made it able that the User can change the position sort by clicking up or down arrows.

But when I swap once the position, i could not change the position of the changed row anymore.

Here is the function:

```
function switchPosition( data, direction )
{
    var tableName = "artikelposition";
    currentPosition = parseInt( data['position'] );

    if( direction == "up" )
    {
        newPosition = currentPosition - 1;
    }
    else if( direction == "down" )
    {
        newPosition = currentPosition + 1;
    }

    var otherTr = $("tr[data-position='" + newPosition + "']").data("artikelid");
    console.log("clicked object" + data['artikelid'] + " : current position " + data['position'] + " : new position " + newPosition);
    console.log("other objekt" + $("#" + otherTr).data("artikelid") + " : current position " + $("#" + otherTr).data("position") + " : new Position " + currentPosition);

    $( "#" + data['artikelid'] )
        .data({
            "position": newPosition
        });
    $( "#" + data['artikelid'] + " td.tdArticleNumber span.spanPositionNummer" )
        .html( newPosition );


    $( "#" + otherTr )
        .data({
            "position": currentPosition
        });
    $( "#" + otherTr + " td.tdArticleNumber span.spanPositionNummer" )
        .html( currentPosition );

    sortTable( tableName );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As ASGM has already mentioned, problem is with `otherTr`. In this line:

```
var otherTr = $("tr[data-position='" + newPosition + "']").data("artikelid");
```

I still don't know why this expression always returns `data-artikelid` of first `tr`, but if you somewhy want to save your code, than you can use replace this line with something like:

```
$("#artikelposition tr").each(function()
{
    var that = $(this);
    if (that.data("position") == newPosition)
    {
        otherTr = that.data('artikelid');
    }
});
```

As Pawel said [there in comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4191386/jquery-how-to-find-an-element-based-on-a-data-attribute-value/4191718#4191718), problem is that `data-position` is set dynamically. But even his idea to use `$("...").attr("data-...", value)` seems not to work there.

Comment: Good to see a solution that keeps the original code, in case that's what OP wants.

Comment: @ASGM yea, thanks, even though your one not only is more elegant, but also protects from `newPosition = -1` and `newPosition = 4`

Comment: thanks a lot. this was the right code. Because i need the id of the tr for my ajax-functions. the code works

Answer (score 1):

You can probably accomplish this with a lot less code (see [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eVz69/2/)):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".rowUp,.rowDown").click(function(){
        var row = $(this).parents("tr:first");
        if ($(this).is(".rowUp")) {
            row.prev().find(".spanPositionNummer").html(row.index() + 1);
            row.insertBefore(row.prev());

        } else {
            row.next().find(".spanPositionNummer").html(row.index() + 1);
            row.insertAfter(row.next());
        }
        row.find(".spanPositionNummer").html(row.index() + 1);
    });
});
```

You can attach a click handler to the images and user `insertBefore()` to move the rows.  You can also use the built-in `index()` function (rather than fiddling with `data-position`) to set the position number `span`.

(Based on the answer from [How to move table row in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1569889/jquery-move-table-row))

---

Or if you want to do this with your existing code, the bug seems to be that you're selecting the wrong `otherTr`.

When you first click the down arrow on the top row, you can see in the console that the selected row is moved from position 1 to 2, and the middle row is moved from 2 to 1:

```
Angeklicktes Objekt2445 : aktuelle Position 1 : neue Position 2 (index):59
Anderes Objekt2501 : aktuelle Position 2 : neue Position 1 (index):60
```

But when you click the bottom arrow on what's now the top row, this is what the console logs:

```
Angeklicktes Objekt2501 : aktuelle Position 1 : neue Position 2 (index):59
Anderes Objekt2501 : aktuelle Position 1 : neue Position 1 (index):60
```

Note that the top row is (correctly) being moved from position 1 to 2.  But immediately afterwards, the same row (`Objekt2501`, referenced by the same position) is instructed to move from 1 to 1.

Comment: Much more elegant code, that's for sure :) But I still can't figure out why original code doesn't work