# Failed to execute 'insertBefore' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'

Tags: javascript, error-handling, split, tablesorter

How do I troubleshoot this error? What did I do wrong that may have caused this?

In the Chrome console, I get Failed to execute 'insertBefore' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'. for this line of code

```
rows[i].parentNode.insertBefore(rows[i + 1], rows[i]);
```

Which can be found towards the end. I don't know how to fix this error or wht this error is.

```
console.log("CONNECTED");
var n = 1;
tester(n);

function tester(n){
var switchcount = 0;
var  table = document.getElementById("myTable2");
var monthsArray= ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"];//0-11    

var switching = true;
// Set the sorting direction to ascending:
var dir = "asc";
// Check the status of each data cell in a table. 
while(switching){
    switching = false;
    var rows = table.rows;      
    var shouldSwitch;

    for (var i = 1; i < (rows.length-1); i++) { 
        var cellsX = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("TD")[n];
        var cellsY = rows[i + 1].getElementsByTagName("TD")[n];
        var dateX = cellsX.textContent.split(" ");
        var dateY = cellsY.textContent.split(" ");
        var mnthX = dateX[0];
        var mnthY = dateY[0];
        var yearX = dateX[1];
        var yearY = dateY[1];
        var totalX = parseInt(monthsArray.indexOf(mnthX)) + parseInt(yearX);
        var totalY = parseInt(monthsArray.indexOf(mnthY)) + parseInt(yearY);

        if(dir === "asc"){
            if(totalX < totalY) {
                //if so, mark as a switch and break the loop:
                shouldSwitch = true;
                break;
            }
        }else if(dir === "desc"){
            if(totalX > totalY){
                shouldSwitch = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    if(shouldSwitch){
        rows[i].parentNode.insertBefore(rows[i + 1], rows[i]);
        switching = true;
        switchcount++;
    }else{
        if (switchcount === 0 && dir === "asc") {
            dir = "desc";
            switching = true;
        }

    }
}
```

}

my table that I'm sorting by month and year.

```
<table id ="myTable2">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Client</th>
            <th>Due Date</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Smith</td>
            <td>Apr 18</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Kelly</td>
            <td>Jan 18</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Park</td>
            <td>Nov 18</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Mark</td>
            <td>July 19</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: `var rows = table.rows;`  What does that give you?

Comment: @jmargolisvt he read-only HTMLTableElement property rows returns a live HTMLCollection of all the rows in the table, including the rows contained within any <thead>, <tfoot>, and <tbody> elements.

Although the property itself is read-only, the returned object is live and allows the modification of its content. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableElement/rows

Comment: There's a jQuery solution that you might be able to adapt to your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1569889/how-to-move-table-row-in-jquery

Comment: @ControlAltDel I'm trying to learn vanilla JS first before moving to JQuery and other JS libraries. Thank you for the link.

Comment: Just comment out the `rows[i].parentNode.insertBefore(rows[i + 1], rows[i]);` and run. You'll see your while loop is ifinite.

Comment: @JamesParker re: trying to learn vanilla JS first... I totally get it, absolutely. But there are two problems with the concept of vanilla JS: One is that JavaScript can work differently between different browsers / engines. The other is that the DOM can be organized differently in different browsers... JQuery actually takes care of some of this for you, which is a good reason to learn it.

Comment: @ControlAltDel When using JQuery can you do custom sorting? If not could one write something in JS to do it? I also was told that JQuery has some unnecessary overhead for the end user. I'm so new to this, web development can be quite over whelming. Once again thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edited answer:**

There is no `rows[i+1]` when you `i` is the index of the final element of the row. Your issue is that in the above part of your code, `i` is the value that `i` had after the `for` loop, which is the first value at which the loop test `i < (rows.length-1)` failed. Therefore, at this point of the code, you should always have `i === (rows.length-1)`, which is not what you want.

A way to avoid this issue of using a loop variable outside of the loop (which is rarely the goal and always hard to read/understand/debug etc) is to write your loops with `let` instead of `var`, if you don't mind not supporting older browsers:

```
for (let i = 1; i < (rows.length-1); i++) {
```

That way, `i` won't be defined outside of your loop, and you'll have an easy-to-understand error telling you about it if you happen to try and use `i` further down your code at a place at which it doesn't mean anything.

---

However there are still other mistakes in the code. In particular, you never actually get out of your `while` loop. Hopefully you can figure this out by yourself now that you know how to fix the error you had. But if I had to sort a table using plain JavaScript, I would probably:

- Get a list of all the rows in my table,
- Sort these using [the build-in sort function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) with a well-chosen compare function,
- Remove all the rows from the DOM using [remove](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/remove),
- Add them back in the correct order using [appendChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) in a `for` loop over the sorted array.

That'd be much easier to read and to debug. Writing your own sort function is a good exercise but if your goal is a web functionality and not practicing algorithmics, don't do it.

Comment: I thought using rows.length-1 would skip the table head

Comment: @JamesParker Wait, you're right. I misread that somehow... I thought the line causing the issues was inside the `for` loop, but it isn't. Let me update my answer.

Comment: I added a blank array item at index 0 and my error went away. So I'm thinking When Jan = 0 but  row 0 was the header. Therefore it broke??? I think